# Comparing matrices of different shapes

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Say I have two matrices of different shape, `A` and `B`. I would like to compare them on the intersection.

That is, `A` = `a1`x`a2` and `B` = `b1`x`b2`. Let

```
A = np.ones((3, 4))
B = np.ones((5, 2))
```

then the intersection would be `(3, 2)`. The next step would be to crop both matrices into `(3, 2)` and to the comparison.

I am able to do these things using `numpy`, but it all looks very inefficient and inelegant. What would be a short and clean way of achieving this for two-dimensional `A`, `B`?

Comment: Share your working code and add a sample case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for the largest possible subarray that fits inside both `A` and `B`. You could just compare each dimension of `A` and `B` and take whichever is smallest:

```
def largest_subarray(A, B):
    dims = np.minimum(A.shape, B.shape)         # find smallest dimensions
    idx = tuple(slice(None, dd) for dd in dims) # construct tuple of slice indices
    return A[idx], B[idx]                       # index into A and B
```

For your example arrays it will return `A[:3, :2], B[:3, :2]`.